# How is completeness proved?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

How is, for example, Goedel's Completeness theorem, proved if it requires a formula to be true in *every* model, given that we may not be able to exhaust all possible models?

Comment: What do you mean by “we may not be able to exhaust all possible models”?

Comment: The way the (standard) proof works is we assume a sentence isn’t provable from a given theory and then show there is a model of that theory in which the sentence is false.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Oh, so it is a proof using modus tollens. Do you mind put it as an answer so that I can pick it? A reference presentation of that proof will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We only need to show a theory $T$ is consistent iff it has a model: If so, then given a formula $\phi$ that is undecidable in $T$, then $T\cup\{\phi\}$ and $T\cup\{\neg\phi\}$ are both consistent, hence both have models.

Therefore we don't have to exhaust all models, but (find a way to) build only one model from $T$. [Henkin's approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leon_Henkin#The_completeness_proof) can be found in most modern logic books.